PGFPlots library fillbetween causing a bunch of "Missing Character" warnings
When trying to shade the area between 2 paths using the fillbetween pgfplotslibrary, I'm getting the following warnings:
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!

I more or less just copied the code from the examples in the documentation and modified the parameters a little. What I noticed is that there is some invisible ".01pt" text, which is nowhere in my original code. By redefining nullfont, I can make it visible. Here's an example, uncomment the 3rd line to make the text visible:
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

%\font\nullfont=cmr10

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\pgfplotsset{samples = 100}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin = -4, xmax = 4, 
        ymin = 0, ymax = 10,
        axis lines = center,
        width = 0.99 \linewidth,
        height = 0.66 \linewidth
    ]
        % x-axis path
        \path[
            name path = xaxis
        ]
        (-4, 0) -- (4, 0);
        
        % Plot 1
        \addplot[
            color      = blue,
            line width = 0.3mm,
            domain     = -4:4,
            name path  = plot1
        ]
        {
            8.5 - x^2
        };

        % Shaded area
        \addplot[
            color        = gray,
            fill         = gray,
            fill opacity = 0.25
        ]
        fill between[
            of        = plot1 and xaxis,
            soft clip = {domain = -4:4}
        ];
        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Here a screenshot of my output with the redefinition commented out:

And with it uncommented:

Is this something that can be fixed, or can the warnings at least be suppressed? It doesn't really seem like this invisible text causes any actual problems in the output. I have a lot of such plots in my work and all of these warnings make it very difficult to notice actual warnings.

This has been reported and fixed in the development version:
https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/456
Basically you have to use \ifdim instead of \ifnum in an internal command:
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

%\font\nullfont=cmr10

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\pgfplotsforeachtodomain@@{\ifnum}{\ifdim}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\pgfplotsset{samples = 100}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin = -4, xmax = 4, 
        ymin = 0, ymax = 10,
        axis lines = center,
        width = 0.99 \linewidth,
        height = 0.66 \linewidth
    ]
        % x-axis path
        \path[
            name path = xaxis
        ]
        (-4, 0) -- (4, 0);
        
        % Plot 1
        \addplot[
            color      = blue,
            line width = 0.3mm,
            domain     = -4:4,
            name path  = plot1
        ]
        {
            8.5 - x^2
        };

        % Shaded area
        \addplot[
            color        = gray,
            fill         = gray,
            fill opacity = 0.25
        ]
        fill between[
            of        = plot1 and xaxis,
            soft clip = {domain = -4:4}
        ];
        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

